# How to compress a file to tar in python

Tags: python, tar

May I know what I need to modify or add to my import script for me to compress a csv file to .tar?

**My script**

```
export_csv(
     my_csv=my_csv,
    sheet_id=gsheet_name(worksheet_name)
)

shutil.move(my_csv, '/home/admin/processedCSV')

# If its possible my plan is after moving the CSV file to another folder that time the tar extraction will execute. 
print ('DONE')
```

Let me know if you need more details. TYIA

Comment: For what it's worth, `tar` is just an archive format, not a compressed format. Modern tools like `zip` provide both archiving (combining many files into one container) and compression, but `tar` only does the former. However, Python's `tarfile` module can transparently create a `.tar.gz` (or `.bz2` etc) which is also compressed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `tarfile` module in the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html.